# What does "C'est vite dit" mean?

Tags: sens, adjectifs

[image]

I  don't understand what the underlined words mean. Please tell me if I'm wrong but "vite" in that phrase is an adjective and not an adverb right?

I don't know the meaning of "vite" in that sentence, but I think it refers to le grand schtroumpf when he asked them to protect the village and behave properly.

Please enlighten me on this matter. What is the meaning of that phrase in that context?

Comment: With all those weird verbs starting with "schtroumpf..." you're only confused about the meaning of "C'est vite dit" ?? (Just joking!)

Comment: It's an adverb. Lit: quick to say.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The worried Smurf is reacting to Papa Smurf's "... et tout schtroumpfera bien" as you suspect, but I interpret Papa's words to be a reassuring "everything will be all right" (*tout sera bien*) and not an order to "behave properly."

With this interpretation of Papa's words in mind, I read the response at issue as:

> "Everything will be all right." [Yeah, right] that's easy [for him] to
>   say [since he's flying safely away from the danger facing us here at
>   the village].

"Easy" in my English translation above would be an adjective, but another way of translating it (without the specific dig at Papa) would be:

> "Everything will be all right." [Yeah, right] that's easily said!,

where the "easily" would be an adverb and correspond directly with the use of "vite" as an **adverb** in the French version.

Answer (score 6):

in this case 'C'est vite dit' can best be translated as 'easier said than done'